# "World and its colours" (or colors) makes sense?

Tags: present-simple

does this phrase makes sense: 
"World and its colours?
I would like to use it as a username, but is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The world and its colours" makes perfect sense.

Without the article it is odd, and I can't think of any contexts in which you might say it. But there really isn't any grammar of usernames which would stop you if you wanted.

Comment: +1 I agree. Even given that it can be tricky to pin down what a *phrase* means, it does sound strange without the article.